# Conditionally Rewrite Email Headers (From & Reply-To) Exchange 2010

Tags: email, exchange, rewrite, conditional, smtp-headers

I have a client who maintains Company A (with email addresses %username%@companyA.com) and they own the domain companyB.com however there is no "infrastructure" (no Exchange server) set up specifically for companyB.com.  My client needs to be able to have the end users within it's company (companyA.com) add a specific word or phrase to the Subject (or Body) line of the Outgoing email (they are only concerned with outgoing, incoming is a non-issue in this case) that triggers the Exchange 2010 servers to rewrite the header From and Reply-To username@companyA.com with username@companyB.com but this re-write should ONLY occur if the user places the key word/phrase in the Subject (or Body).

I have attempted using Transport Rules and the New-AddressRewriteEntry cmdlet however each seems to have a limitation.  From what I can tell Transport Rules cannot re-write the From/Reply-To fields and New-AddressRewriteEntry cannot be conditionally triggered based on message content.

So to recap:

User sends email outside the organization: From and Reply-To remain username@companyA.com

User sends email outside the organization WITH "**KeyWord**" in the Subject or Body: From and Reply-To change to username@companyB.com automatically.

Anyone know how this could be done WITHOUT coding a new Mail Agent?  I don't have the programming knowledge to code a custom Agent... I can use any function of Exchange Management Shell or Console. Alternatively if anyone knows of a simple add-on program that could do this that would be good too. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!!!

Comment: Did you ever get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the only way to do what you want is programming. Hire someone if you can't write a program yourself.

Best regards,
Victor

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong in my assumption, but I'm guessing what you really want to achieve is sending mail as a different user from Exchange. You can do this without any programming by creating a distribution group and running:`Add-RecipientPermission <DistroGroup> -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee <User>` Also, you'll want to add the user to the recipients of the distribution group.